# Got error: "Uncaught Error: Service firestore is not available" while working with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm working on a website, and have decided to use Firebase as a host/database server. I use npm to manage my Firebase sdk, and I have run into an error while trying to import Firestore into my site. My firestore database is readable and writable on the dev console, so it definitely exists.

To fix the issue, I decided to make a firebase.js where I import from Firebase and then export my database to use on other pages and scripts. Here are firebase.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from "./node_modules/firebase/firebase-app.js"
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc } from './node_modules/firebase/firebase-firestore.js';

const firebaseConfig = {
    //config
};  
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export const db = getFirestore(app)
export { collection, addDoc}
```

The above gives me the error:

```
provider.ts:130 Uncaught Error: Service firestore is not available
```

The reason I am using /node_modules/firebase instead of just firebase/ is because it gives me the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/firebase-app.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

If I use a static page, like https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.19.1/firebase-firestore.js as my import location, it will say

```
provider.ts:130 Uncaught Error: Service firestore is not available
```

I've seen 2 other posts relating to this and tried the suggestions there, but none of it was any help. Other import statements work as my package.json has "type": "module" and for my dependencies, I had {"firebase": "^9.19.1"}. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: got the same error, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I'm still having this issue, but only on a specific project—however, the code of this project is the exact same as a previous one, in how it's initialized. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Using the newer version worked for me.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-app.js'
import { getFirestore } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-firestore.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated solution

While searching for a solution to this issue—as I ran into it on a specific project, but not on another with the same code—I found there was a reported issue in the Next.js repo, with this error. The solution ended up being related to how Firebase is initialized.

Firebase's docs say to initialize Firebase like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  //...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

*[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75974081/got-error-uncaught-error-service-firestore-is-not-available-while-working-wi#comment136637521_75974081)*

Although this has worked flawlessly for me in the past, this is actually not a best practice as it relates to Next.js.

Kenneth Ivan Pineda ([**djkenneth** on GitHub](https://github.com/djkenneth)) shows a screenshot of how he initializes Firebase in his projects, shedding some light into a better practice:

```
import { getApp, getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENT_ID
｝；

// InitializeFirebase

const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();

export const db = getFirestore(app);

export const auth = getAuth(app);

export default app;
```

*[Reference](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/33798#discussioncomment-4530868)*

Of course, in this example, we see that he does more than just `initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`. The addition of the logic that checks whether Firebase has been initialized is important for Next.js. This logic prevents Firebase from initializing more than necessary, and makes sure it is properly initialized before we run `getFirestore()`.